# JQuery clone li+children, update text (in child tag), and append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, clone, innerhtml

I have some pretty cool CSS that I want to reuse in a `<ul>`. I want to clone an existing `<li>` (so that I can reuse CSS), update a `<p>` field, and then append it to the end of the `<ul>`.

I know I can do something like this to find...

```
var temp = $(".chatboxcontent").find('li');
console.log(temp);
```

And then I can use `.clone` like so... (is this correct?)

```
var temp2 = temp.clone
```

So then I need to delete a `<p>` and then insert my own `<p>`

The HTML element looks like this...

```
<div class="chatboxcontent">
        <li class="current-user-message">
    <div class="avatar">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
    </div>
    <div class="chatboxmessagecontent">
      <p>test</p>
      <time datetime="2016-07-28 16:45:20 UTC" title="28 Jul  2016 at 04:45PM">
        16:45 PM
      </time>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="current-user-message">
    <div class="avatar">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
    </div>
    <div class="chatboxmessagecontent">
      <p>test</p>

...and so on
```

I need to delete then insert text in the `<p>test</p>` element and then append it to the `class="chatboxcontent"`

I'm thinking something like this...

```
var message_li = $(".chatboxcontent").find('li').clone();
$(message_li).innerHTML("p") = data.text;
$(".chatboxcontent").append(message_li);
```

From the above I get `$(...).innerHTML is not a function`. So how do I delete the element and then insert it?

Is there a better way to implement this?

Comment: Instead of `$(message_li).innerHTML("p") = data.text;` use `$(message_li).find("p").html(data.text);`

Comment: That works, but it isn't including the CSS. In other words, it just inserts it here `<li class="current-user-message">the quick</li>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$(".chatboxcontent") //Select the conatiner
.find('li:first') //Find the first 'li' element
.clone() //then clone it
.find('p') //Find the 'p' tag inside the cloned element
.html(data.text) // change the html of the 'p' tag
.end() // Return to the cloned 'li' with the 'p' tag changed
.appendTo('.chatboxcontent'); // append the cloned 'li' to the conatiner
```

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/iRbouh/x4h69939/

I hope this will help.

Comment: `Invalid or unexpected token` it complains at the `appendTo()` (because of the `.end()`?)

Comment: I think there was an invalid character in the `appendTo` it's working now please check out the demo !

Comment: Perfect! this is exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

Where you have `$(message_li).innerHTML("p") = data.text;`, you need to replace it with `$(message_li).html(data.text);`

Also, if `data.text` isn't already wrapped in a `<p>` tag like you wanted, you can also do the following:

`$(message_li).html('<p>' + data.text + '</p>');`

**Another solution, and what I would personally do, is the following:**

```
$('<li>').addClass('current-user-message').html($('.chatboxcontent').find('li').html()).appendTo(message_li);
```

Then include the CSS for `.current-user-message` in an external stylesheet.

Comment: Ok this is good, however something it wrong with my implementation of the `clone()` function. I want it to clone the element plus all of it's children. It should clone all of `. chatboxmessagecontent` and then insert the message into the `<p>` tag. I need this to happen because I need to maintain the CSS code within the `li` tag

Comment: Updated post title to better describe the implementation

Comment: If the class for every `.current-user-message` is the same, why not just include a stylesheet which will then be applied when you add a new `.current-user-message` via jQuery?